# How to get Dragged Elements final position with Framer motion in react Js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, positioning, framer-motion

I was trying to build a React Application where the user can Drag any element of the page. But after the page refresh, the element gets back to its original position. How can I achieve the feature that even after a page refresh the dragged element won't get back to its previous position?

So I was trying to get the final position when dragged end. I tried with the event. clientX also with offsetX value. And put this X, and Y coordinates to the initial position of the element so that I can check if its position starts where I left it by dragging. But it seems like  It is not holding its previous position.

This is my div. Inside that div, I have an image that I am dragging.

```
    <motion.div
      drag
      dragMomentum={false}
      dragConstraints={{
        right: 1200,
      }}
      initial={{ x: -1, y: 367 }}
      ref={myRef}
      onDragStart={(event, info) => {
        initailPosition(event, info);
      }}
      onDragEnd={(event, info) => {
        finalPosition(event, info);
      }}
      className={Style.imgCntainer}
    >
      <img
        onPointerDown={(e) => {
          dragControls.start(e);
        }}
        className={Style.file}
        src={data[0]?.fileLink}
        alt="img"
      />
</motion.div>
```

And the functions are

```
 const finalPosition = (event, info) => {
        console.log("end", info.offset.y, info.offset.x);
    }

    const initailPosition = (event, info) => {
        console.log("start", info.offset.y, info.offset.x);
    }
```

I was trying to find the initial position before dragging the element and the final position after the drag ended. But seems like there is something cause I am not getting the exact position.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: Why do you need to 'reload' the page while having many things happening on that page? It's because React or Vue or Angular is kind of SPA, which is their purpose to avoid reloading the whole page but re-render the update DOM instead.

Back to your question: the only thing which is not reset when you reload the React page is ref value. So, you can use useRef hook to store the original value, final value for your purpose, but I would encourage you to review your application flow to avoid reload the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the accurate example but you can examine the way I'm getting last coordinates for a div [on my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-save-coords-after-drag-and-open-at-the-same-coords-eg6jnh?file=/src/App.tsx)

The problem with "event" and "info" in onDragEnd/onDragStart callbacks is seems to be that it gives back the coordinates of your mouse pointer when you started or ended dragging. So you cannot accurately position your div(s) using the coords of offsetX/clientX.

The only way I found to exactly position the div is to get the transform style (framer-motion use transform for positioning) via ref and cutting the needed x/y values out via regex.

Hope that helps.